# Deligne-Mumford moduli spaces and compactification of symmetric matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, algebraic-curves, compactifications

The real Deligne-Mumford moduli space $\bar M_{0,n+1}(\mathbb R)$ of stable genus
zero curves with $n+1$ marked points is a compactification of the space of
configurations of $n$ distinct ordered points on the real line modulo affine
transformations.  This space is a smooth projective variety and carries a
natural action of the permutation group $S_n$.  We can interpret the
configurations of distinct points on the real line as *diagonal* $n\times n$
matrices with distinct eigenvalues, $S_n$ acting via conjugation with signed
permutation matrices.

**Question**:  What is the right compactification of the space of *arbitrary* symmetric $n\times n$ matrices with distinct eigenvalues modulo affine transformations?  I am looking for a projective variety carrying a natural $SO(n)$-action, such that if we restrict to diagonal matrices, we recover $\bar M_{0,n+1}(\mathbb R)$ with the above $S_n$-action.  Is this variety smooth?  Does it have an interpretation in terms of curves with marked points?

Comment: Can you please remind me how the group of affine transformations of $\mathbb{C}$ acts on the space of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices?

Comment: Everything is over $\mathbb R$.  The group of affine transformations $x\mapsto ax+b$ of $\mathbb R$ acts on symmetric matrices by $S\mapsto aS+bI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.